# Как получить инфо о бэкграунде любого View в android studio?

Tags: android, background

Нужно написать условие if, не знаю как правильно это сделать.
В условии надо задать что то наподобие этого "если бэкграунд данного View задан значение х, тогда менять этот х на скажем y".

дополнительное инфо: Как менять бэкграунд знаю, недавно находил в стаковерфлоу, в смысле здесь, а вот как получить инфо и что еще важнее - как правильно провести сравнение (правильно ли использовать equals()?) - не знаю.

Просьба: В ответе написать пример решение данной проблемы в виде кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ColorDrawable colorView = (ColorDrawable) view.getBackground();
int color = colorView .getColor();
```

Далее, сравнивайте полученный цвет с `x`.

Наверно, у вас `x` будет задан как строковая переменная. Преобразуйте строку в число:

```
String x = "#2222FF"
int myColor = Color.parseColor(x);
```

А потом сравнивайте:

```
if (color == myColor)
```

---

**UPD**

Если вам нужно получить бэкграунд как `Drawable`, то это делается так:

```
Drawable background = view.getBackground()
```

Далее, сравнить две картинки можно способом [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31562099/7485582):

```
public static boolean areDrawablesIdentical(Drawable drawableA, Drawable drawableB) {
    Drawable.ConstantState stateA = drawableA.getConstantState();
    Drawable.ConstantState stateB = drawableB.getConstantState();
    // If the constant state is identical, they are using the same drawable resource.
    // However, the opposite is not necessarily true.
    return (stateA != null && stateB != null && stateA.equals(stateB))
            || getBitmap(drawableA).sameAs(getBitmap(drawableB));
}

public static Bitmap getBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap result;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        result = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    } else {
        int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        // Some drawables have no intrinsic width - e.g. solid colours.
        if (width <= 0) {
            width = 1;
        }
        if (height <= 0) {
            height = 1;
        }

        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Автор отмечает, что метод требует память для хранения картинок.

---

Также я могу вам посоветовать не заниматься сравниванием картинок напрямую, а записывать текущее состояние view, например, в `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: А если бэкграунд не обьязательно чтобы с одного цвета на другую переключалась а с цвета на drawable? Ну скажем в drawable я использую скажем одну png картинку и мой интерес состоит в том, чтобы эту картинку показать вначале в одном view а потом нажать на один созданный button и  через OnClickListener() этого button-а поменять использование этой png картинки на другой View?

Comment: @RubenKubalyan, обновил ответ

Comment: Android studio "cannot resolve method bytesEqualTo()"  - Метод в классе Drawable отсутствует.

Comment: " Drawable drawable1 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.pika_pika);

               drawable1.bytesEqualTo(background_iv5);"

Comment: @RubenKubalyan, да, в ответе, на который я ссылался, была ссылка на GitHub  с самописными функциями, правда, на Kotlin. Обновил ответ. Всё-таки советую просто как-нибудь запоминать, что за картинка установлена. Это будет намного проще.